# How to receive data using Domino webservice provider

Tags: web-services, lotus-domino, lotusscript, domino-designer-eclipse

I have an external application that should send and recieve data from a Domino web service provider.
I managed to create a webservice proivider using lotusscript that send data back to the caller

I need to know how to receive data from the caller using the provider and add it to Domino?  could not find any example on the internet, is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code of the provider (I call it wsOfDomino), you add a function, just put parameter(s) to this function.

```
Class wsOfDomino
  function getWSdata( userName as string) as string
    getWSdata = "Hello " + userName
  End Function
End Class
```

Domino will generate the WSDL, in which the external application will "see" that it can send to Domino the userName.

Change userName and name of the function according your needs.

Comment: thanks, any idea how to receive an XML file instead of a string?

Comment: or an object containg data

Comment: Have you seen this? http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/nd7-webservices/
It discusses passing complex data types as LotusScript classes. Also, uou can send XML or just about anything else as a string - as long as both sides know about it and do the enccoding/decoding and processing appropriately.

Comment: As @RichardSchwartz mentionned, the external application can send XML in a string parameter. on the external side, use "<![CDATA[" + xmlTobeSent + "]]>").On the Domino side your just have to get the xml in the parameter.